# jQuery animated scroll to anchor not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I thought I had resolved this issue but turns out i hadn't. Basically building a tumblr theme and something in my code is conflicting with the jquery animated scroll to top. I've tried removing things as I'm not entirely sure what it could be and thought it might be really obvious to somebody else?

Here is a link to my theme http://minori-theme.tumblr.com/ and a jsfiddle that I was following in order to animate the smooth scroll http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/1008/

The code I'm using is below and I'm just using a standard a link and id which are linking fine as it goes to the correct point its just not smooth scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var hashTagActive = "";
$(".scroll").click(function (event) {
    if(hashTagActive != this.hash) { //this will prevent if the user click several times the same link to freeze the scroll.
        event.preventDefault();
        //calculate destination place
        var dest = 0;
        if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        } else {
            dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        }
        //go to destination
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: dest
        }, 2000, 'swing');
        hashTagActive = this.hash;
    }
});
});
```

Edit: If anyone has a simpler alternative I'm open to suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need you condition `if ($(this.hash).offset().top >` ? ScrollTop works fine if you just use .offset().top of the element as a point of destination

Comment: I didn't get your problem as in your code runs in similar manner as the link you provided just that you have given timeInterval as 2000 ms.. scrolling is smooth in both .. ?

Comment: if your only issue is that it's not smooth, you might be looking for a jQuery UI easing: http://jqueryui.com/easing/ - which one would you like to have? (click on them and see how they work)... you'd need to include jQuery UI in order them to work...

Comment: In the fiddle it works fine, in my theme the link works as it jumps to the top but there is no animation happening. Sorry I'm not great with jQuery. I believe the only issue is that its not scrolling but i can't understand why?

Comment: How would I go about using jquery easing - any tutorials or examples, many thanks!

Comment: I don't get the hashTagActive thing, I'm doing it like this: http://perry.productions/js/script.js

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion just tried that and it's not working i think there is something in the rest of my theme thats conflicting with this and I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Easing effect on your `animate` function won't work if you don't add [**easing libary**](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). jQuery core does not have easing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.compatibility.js"></s‌​cript>
```

Also you can define dynamic value to animate's timing based on your element's offset top value. This will make your animation smoother based on the current value.

[**Here is jsFiddle with smooth scrolling effect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/1014/)

```
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();

         var dest = 0;
         var $target = $(this.hash);
         var targetTop = $target.offset().top;
         var remainTop = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

         if( targetTop > remainTop){
              dest = remainTop;
         }else{
              dest = targetTop;
         }

         // Dynamic value for timing
         var dur = dest*1.2;

         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, dur,'easeInOutCubic');

});
```

And one last note, you should orgnize your code with using variables, these coding of your is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, this doesn't seem to be working live or in the fiddle and also breaks the anchor link.

Comment: @user2498890 you need to add this script if you want to use easing effects: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.compatibility.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks but I tried this also and no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: As you can see its working fine on the fiddle. If its not working on your template, there is something else about tumblr which we can detect. http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/1017/

Comment: It's not working in the jsfiddle as its showing a message saying please stop hot linking my easing script?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll works the first time, but not any time after that. Check through all the var's that get used to see if something is being kept.

EDIT:
The line

```
if(hashTagActive != this.hash)
```

will not bother with the jquery animation if you have already clicked "Back to top" because the hashTagActive is already #top. Thats why it works once but not twice.

EDIT 2:
Check out [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/1020/)  for a way around it

Comment: He does not having problems with scrolling destination mate. He is trying to make animation smoother

Comment: Yes - the problem is the code doesn’t bother with the jquery animation after the first time you click "back to top". That's why its not smooth.

Comment: He is a she - thanks for your answer, how to do I edit exactly, do i need to remove the line?

Comment: You could put a callback function in your animate call to clear hashTagActive once the animation has finished. This would mean that you disable it during the animation and clear it when done. See edit 2 above