# JQuery anchor scrolling with bounce effect

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to figure out how to write an anchor scrolling with bounce effect.
www.antecmotive.com
an example from that site, when you click the top nav, it will scroll to that section, but you can see it scroll over the section a little bit down, then go back up to the correct place.

I only have the following code for normal scrolling.

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('#nav a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain animation to achieve what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/ry1gvd03/

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ctrl = $($.attr(this, 'href'));

    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(ctrl).offset().top + 50
    }, 500, function () {

        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(ctrl).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are using a plugin called jQuery Easing http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

I think the easing method you want is "easeOutBack". I modified an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379041/4006027)

```js
 $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var dest = 0;
   var $target = $(this.hash);
   var targetTop = $target.offset().top;
   var remainTop = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

   if (targetTop > remainTop) {
     dest = remainTop;
   } else {
     dest = targetTop;
   }
   console.log(dest);
   var dur = dest;

   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: dest
   }, dur, 'easeOutBack');

 });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a class="scroll" href="#destination1">Destination 1</a>
  <a class="scroll" href="#destination2">Destination 2</a>
  <a class="scroll" href="#destination3">Destination 3</a>
  <a class="scroll" href="#destination4">Destination 4</a>
</nav>


<section id="destination1">
  <h1>Block 1</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="destination2">
  <h1>Block 2</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="destination3">
  <h1>Block 3</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</section>

<section id="destination4" style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
  <h1>Block 4</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</section>
```